# Authentication failure on twitter

Tags: oauth, twitter-oauth

401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
Failed to validate oauth signature and token

TwitterException{exceptionCode=[8e063946-ef59cf90], statusCode=401, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.1}
Failed to get timeline: 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
Failed to validate oauth signature and token

```
at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:82)
at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:116)
at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:98)
at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:287)
at joo.App.main(App.java:43)
```

I am trying to update status on twitter via twitter API but every time i execute my program following error arises although i have supplied consumer key and consumer asecret key.

If anyone have solution. please help me.
thank You

Comment: Could you share the relevant code from your program?